# Logical optimization of joins and selections

Tags: relational-theory, optimization, query-performance

I am studying query optimization. I have read that it might be preferred to apply relational selections before a logical join operation. Is there a scenario where joining first and then applying selections would be desirable?

I searched for an example of this, and found that people seemed to be saying that a query with conjunctions might benefit from this, but it is not clear to me why this should be. This is not a question about how a particular query optimizer in a particular commercial product performs, it is a question of logic.

An example would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Inner Joining allows joining first and then selection and it would be optimized approach too. Example:

```
SELECT * FROM employee,**(Inner Joining)** department 
WHERE employee.DepartmentID=department.DepartmentID;
```

Comment: What do you mean with *"select first and then join"*?

Comment: Sample queries would help clarify your thoughts. Also add which DBMS you are asking about. Optimization is quite different across DBMS.

Comment: _Query logic_ does not have much to do with _query optimization_, I don't think. _You_ make sure your query is semantically correct, then _the optimizer_ tries to make it fast while remaining correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are cases where applying the filter after the join is preferable. But they are rare.

Consider this example:

```
SELECT ...
FROM a
INNER JOIN b
  ON b.key = a.key
WHERE a.some_string LIKE '%foo%'
```

Now, assume that very few rows in `a` has a matching row in `b`. It is now faster to first join and remove the rows from `a` that does not match and then apply the expensive string filter.